# What is the difference between SAN vs NAS

Tags: storage-area-network, network-attached-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between SAN,NAS and DAS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/81723/what-is-the-difference-between-san-nas-and-das)

I would like to know the difference between SAN and NAS (explained in basic English before getting too technical).

I saw a few site on this. They have topologies and difference diagrams. I have a vague understanding, but need to make that concrete.

So if somebody can take it from conceptual differences to the technical differences to the implementation differences, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Normally a NAS provides an NFS/SMB share, a SAN provides disks to a system that it uses as disks, rather than a shared area to write to.

So, if you want a document storage area for your colleagues or some source code etc, a NAS is cheaper, because the cheaper ones run a cut down version of linux and pump out the shares using samba and NFS.

Sans are more expensive as they are often fibre based, and you get in effect a direct connection to a portion of disk for a given machine you can treat as your very own.

Answer (score -1):

Wikipedia is very much your friend and mine:

[SAN - Storage Area Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_area_network)

[NAS - Networked Attached Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage)

> One way to loosely conceptualise the
>   difference between a NAS and a SAN is
>   that a NAS appears to the client OS
>   (operating system) as a file server
>   (the client can map network drives to
>   shares on that server) whereas a disk
>   available through a SAN still appears
>   to the client OS as a disk, visible in
>   disk and volume management utilities
>   (along client's local disks), and
>   available to be formatted with a file
>   system and mounted.

(All credit for the above text goes to Wikipedia, not me!)